# How to add attributes to the comment form tag?

Tags: comments, comment-form, html5

How can I add attributes to form tag? Below is my code but it does not add the attributes I need:

```
$args = array(
    'title_reply'=>'',
    'comment_notes_before' => '',
    'logged_in_as' => '',
    'class_form' => 'form-comment form-submit',
    'comment_field' =>  '<div class="medium-12 columns">
        <label>
            <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-input" rows="10" required></textarea>
            <span class="form-error">Yo, you had better fill this out, it\'s required.</span>
        </label>
    </div>',
    'submit_button' => '<div class="medium-12 columns">
            <input type="submit" class="button button-send" value="Send">
        </div>
    '
);
comment_form($args);
```

It generates the `form` tag like this:

```
<form action="http://xxx/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="form-comment form-submit">
```

But I need to add `data-abide novalidate`:

```
<form action="http://xxx/wp-comments-post.php" class="form-comment form-submit" id="formComment" data-abide novalidate method="post">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use this function rather than `comment_form()`

```
function validate_comment_form(){
    ob_start();
    comment_form();
    echo str_replace('<form','<form attribute="value" ',ob_get_clean());
}
```